# System error after upgrade [Kali]

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade

I was doing a distribution upgrade on **kali** from 1.1.0 to 2.0 using:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Upgrade was of 2 GB and after 1 GB download, I wanted to download openssh-server, so i did an apt-get install, but an upgrade message was shown (**apt-get upgrade**) , since it required only 74MB/1GB download, i preferred to do it first, and after installation, i rebooted my laptop and was welcomed with this message:

[image]

I can't login into gui mode but cli mode is available.
I have no idea how to fix it, please help.

P.S.: 
During installation I was asked for some greeting file, it said to choose between downloaded or system file along with a message that system file was modified, so i preferred to choose system file.

Answer (score 0):

kali is an unstable distros
it behaves differently with different machines
i suggest you not to download the upgrade instead go to kali linux offical site and download the newest kali linux version and re install it
it will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have you tried to upgrade your system using CLI ? Or try to re-configure all the packages again.

> sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a

May be it will work for you. If not then you will need to re-format your system with the latest version of KaliLinux.